# Way to log/alert when Maven 'Dependency mediation' resolves to 'nearest definition' between multiple versions of artifact

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I understand that Maven dependency mediation feature determines what version of a dependency will be used when multiple versions are encountered using the "nearest definition" mechanism (closest in the dependency tree). My question is if there is a way to make Maven alert/log it when it does this.

I found that when i was using spring boot & using the starter parent along with other dependencies one of my dependencies got resolved automatically but that caused things to fail at run time which took a while for me to figure out..so was wondering if there is a way to get alerted when Maven does this so i can take some action if needed (explicitly add a dependency, etc.)

Thanks
Muthu

Comment: You should take a look at the maven-enforcer-plugin...related to the rule:https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html

Comment: thanks @khmarbaise will take a look...so looks like i can force the build to fail..